# Is there a way to make rows of content into a column with pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, sass, html-table, responsive

I have a table like this:

```html
<p>On large screens</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way to modify it purely with CSS to **LOOK** like this? (a single column where every odd item is from the first row and every even is from the second row)

```html
<p>On small screens</p>

<div>
 <div>1</div>
 <div>2</div>
 <div>3</div>
 <div>4</div>
 <div>5</div>
 <div>6</div>
</div>
```

I tried to use `display: contents;` but apparently, it does not work on `<tr>`-s for some reason. Any ideas on how I should approach this? Also, I can only use pure (S)CSS. The number of rows and columns is dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS grid like below

```css
table {
  display: grid;
}

table > *, /* you need to target the "tbody" as well as "tr" */
table tr {
  display: contents;
}

td:nth-child(1) {order:1}
td:nth-child(2) {order:2}
td:nth-child(3) {order:3}
/* td:nth-child(n) {order:n} */
```

```html
<p>On large screens</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or a very hacky way that I don't recommend:

```css
table {
  display: grid;
}

table > tbody {
  display: contents;
}

/* the hack is here */
table tr {
  grid-area: 1/1; /* both tr will overlap */
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 2lh; /* you need to make this equal to twice the height of one "td" */
}

/* the second one will show the content at the bottom while the first one will keep the at the top */
table tr:nth-child(2) {
  align-items: end;
}
```

```html
<p>On large screens</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the number of rows and columns is dynamic. I'm sorry. Is there a way to make your solution dynamic?

Comment: @LaczkóÖrs repeat the `td:nth-child(n) {order:n}` as many time as you want, even for a dynamic number of columns you will have a limit so consider that limit

Comment: For all I know there could be 150 columns. I need to make it dynamic rather than hard coded:(

Comment: @LaczkóÖrs added another hacky solution

Comment: This is a very smart solution! I'm amazed. One question tho, how is the support for ˝lh´? Did I read correctly that it's about 85+%?

Comment: @LaczkóÖrs all the browsers support it: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_length_lh (you can always use another unit based on your specific case)

Answer (score 0):

You could have the rows overlayed each other, with the rows separated by the total height of each `<td>` element:

```css
table, td {
  display: block;
}

table {
  position: relative;
}

tr:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.25em;
}

td {
  line-height: 1.25;
  margin-bottom: 1.25em;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>On large screens</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I need to use a Table for semantic reasons.

Comment: I'm sorry, I completely misinterpreted your question. Updated.