# How to alternate div display based on class name

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have the following code to sort two types of equal amounts of elements. However, they are all clumped up. Is there a way to put them into a single column alternating based on class name? E.g. `.item1`, `.item2`, `.item1`, `.item2`, etc.

```css
.item1 {
  grid-area: myArea1;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: myArea2; 
}

.item1, .item2 {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'myArea1' 'myArea2';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item1">11</div>
  <div class="item1">111</div>
  <div class="item1">1111</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item2">22</div>
  <div class="item2">222</div>
  <div class="item2">2222</div>
</div>
```

I'm open to other non-grid, but pure (S)CSS solutions. The number of items is dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hacky way like [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77862354/8620333)

```css
.item1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.item2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  align-self: end;
}


.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0 auto;
  grid-auto-rows: 2lh;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item1">11</div>
  <div class="item1">111</div>
  <div class="item1">1111</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item2">22</div>
  <div class="item2">222</div>
  <div class="item2">2222</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is good. It definitely ensures the items snap to the intended column, unlike my answer that defers that to the browser's understanding of the `columns` css rule. Nice!

Comment: This seems to work thank you! Give me a sec to implement it in my project, and I'll accept it.

Comment: What if the line height of the items differ?

Comment: @LaczkóÖrs then it won't work. This is a specific "hacky" solution that works for the specific case you shared.

Answer (score -2):

As long as you know generally how many (or can calculate how many programmatically, you could try using `columns: 2;` (or however many columns) on your `grid-container` div's css.

```css
.grid-container {
  columns: 2;
}
```

Like this [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jakemclelland/t3gh6du5/1/)

See the documentation on [columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need to have 1 single column!